# How to prevent changing state of a scrollbar of main content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

By default the fancybox plugin hides a scrollbar and shows another scrollbar that is not scrollable.

Particularly when you activate the plugin without any options it hides a scrollbar of a main content and shows another 'not scrollable' scrollbar.

E.g. you configure the plugin like so:

```
$( document ).ready(    function() { $( '.fancybox' ).fancybox(); } );
```

How can I deny to hide the main scrollbar and how not to show the not scrollable scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            locked : false
        }
    }
});
```